# Error with \ressubheading

Tags: errors

I have this code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10.5pt]{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}


\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}



\begin{document}

\ressubheading{AAA}{Oct 2022 - current}{BBBB}

\end{document}
```

returns the following errors

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
\inaccessible
l.19
Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
\inaccessible
l.19
Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.
Runaway argument?
{
! Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.19
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
! Missing { inserted.
<inserted text>
{
l.19
I've put in what seems to be necessary to fix
the current column of the current alignment.
Try to go on, since this might almost work.
Overfull \hbox (139.75499pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 19--20
```

any idea? Thanks

Comment: There are several problems with your code. First of all the unmotivated `\item` before `\resubheading`. Next: You are defining a command with 4 argument but use only 3, so the `\end` of `\end{document}` is read as 4th argument etc. But because I don't know the expected result, I cannot show code, that corrects all your mistakes.

Comment: IMHO this is a [xy problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449/277964) and you should ask a question about your original problem.

Comment: Your changed question still has several problems like the second one I've told in my first comment. Your usage of `\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}` is also not correct.

Comment: @cabohah the `\item` was from a itemize, I forgot to remove it. I'd like to have a two lines where in the first you have the elements on the far left and on the far right. In the second line only one element on the far left. So, indeed, I have to put `[3]` and remove `\textit{#4}`. Still I get some error. Even just running the following ```\begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{AAA} & 123123 \\
        \textit{BBBB} &  \\
\end{tabular*}```

Comment: Please don't hide information relevant for the question in comments. The question itself should be self-containing and describe the original problem, you've tried to solve. See also the links in my previous comments.

Comment: @cabohah oh good find, the question is a duplicate (but the answer here is better:-) I wonder if we should close the old one as a duplicate of this? (although I agree with you the real problem is unstated and just not using the code at all might be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `\usepackage{array}` so that the tocloft commands are safe in a tabular preamble and use the missing 4th argument of the command you defined. An delete the incorrect `10.5pt` option.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}


\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{%
\begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}



\begin{document}

\ressubheading{AAA}{Oct 2022 - current}{BBBB}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't the `\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}` useless? I get the same result https://i.imgur.com/Ih9lBjr.png with and without.

Comment: @cabohah oh I didn't look at the output I just explained the error (the standard tabular expands the table preamble and the tocloft commands are not robust and explode) I'd have expected a dotfill leader there but you are correct you do not get one, but I don't really know tocloft at all